# JPA Lock Mode behaviour

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, openjpa

I have a java method running in transaction where I read an Oracle database table using following JPA query and then insert a new record in the same table using the result from the following query. I want to understand how lock mode `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` will work in this scenario. Will the whole table be locked when THE following query is executed, blocking other reads from this table until my method commits the transaction after insert?

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "findByMaxSeqForGivenOrd", query = "select ar from Remark ar 
where ar.sequenceNumber = (select max(ar1.remarkId.sequenceNumber) from Remark ar1 
where ar1.remarkId.orderNum = ar.remarkId.orderNum 
AND ar1.remarkId.orderNum=:orderNum)", 
lockMode=LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, 
hints = @QueryHint( name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = 
"3000"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` on a query, then you would end up adding an equivalent of `Serializable` isolation level on oracle db.

On the database level only the rows corresponding to the result entities will be locked with few things to consider:

- Entity relationships for which the locked entity contains the foreign key will also be locked, but not the state of the referenced entities (unless those entities are explicitly locked).
- `ElementCollections` and relationships for which the entity does not containd the foreigh key: `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`; will not be locked by default.
- `ElementCollections` and and relationships owned by the entity that are contained in the join tables will be locked if the 'javax.persistence.lock.scope' property is specified with a value `PessimisticLockScope.EXTENDED`.

Comment: Thanks. So If my table has orderNum and seqNum columns and three records (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), and I am using the query in original question to find record with max(seqNum) for orderNum 1, which would return (1, 2) then for this case another transaction running same query for orderNum 1 will wait until first transaction commits? What about insert? Would other transactions be able to insert new rows for same orderNum:1?

Comment: t2 will wait depending on the timeout setup.. and you cant insert new row with same pk anyway

Comment: I am sorry. I meant insert with different PK. The read I am doing is to generate the new sequence number. I have an existing table where 
orderNum and SeqNum are part of PK. SeqNum resets to 1 for a new orderNum this table currently is being accessed by Pro*c code and now I have to use JPA. I could not find a PK generation strategy that I can use in such case.

Comment: that seems to be a case for different post. The bottom line is that other transactions will be able to read or update the queries entities with that lock mode

Comment: Did you mean other transactions will Not be able to read or update? Or I misunderstood the second comment where you mentioned t2 will wait depending on timeout?

Comment: if the lock is released by t1 and the timeout was not passed, then t2 will access the data, otherwise it will get a PessimisticLockException or a similar one.

Comment: I tested this behavior. I have a finder 'findByMaxSeqForGivenOrd()' and a 'saveBatch()' method that persists. t1 passes findByMaxSeqForGivenOrd and stops at saveBatch(); then t2 come and waits at findByMaxSeqForGivenOrd (I gave a 200 second timeout here). While t2 is waiting t1 saves entities in DB. Only after this t2 executes findByMaxSeqForGivenOrd(), however it gets the same records that t1 got when it executed 'findByMaxSeqForGivenOrd()'. I was expecting for t2 to read the records that t1 persisted?